# Como hacer para que el programa no termine al no insertar nada en la consola. Python

Tags: python

[image: Como hacer para que el programa no termine al no insertar nada en la consola. Python]

Como hacer para que el programa no termine al no insertar nada en la consola. Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está es que estás tratando de convertir a un número entero algo que no lo es mediante la función int() y eso provoca un error que cuelga el programa. Para evitarlo, debes controlar la excepción con un bloque try except:

```
try:
   rinal = int(input("INSERT A NUMBER"))
except ValueError:
   print("No es un número entero")
```

Si quieres que el programa pida al usuario que introduzca un dato hasta que sea un número, podrías meter esas instrucciones dentro de un bucle de la siguiente forma:

```
while True:
    try:
       rinal = int(input("INSERT A NUMBER"))
       break
    except ValueError:
       print("No es un número entero")
```

Comment: usar try, except como control de flujo no es una buena practica, es mejor que lo verifique con otras funciones

Answer (score 1):

Conviertes a int sin comprobar que ha introducido el usuario
Tanto si no introduce nada como si introduce letras, simbolos, ect te dará ese error

```
while True:
    rinal = input('INSERT A NUMBER: ')  # pedimos la introducción de datos
    if rinal.isnumeric(): # comprobamos el dato es un número
        rinal = int(rinal) # aseguramos que el valor es de tipo int
        break
    print('THE VALUE "%s" ISN`T VALID' % rinal)
```

Como puedes comprobar si pruebas la función el programa pedirá el dato hasta recibir un número o pulsar ctrl+c